How to wire up a light using a single phase 240v power supply?
I have a 240v single phase power supply (Nema 6-20) going to one of my shop machines to power the motor. It has 2 hot wires and 1 ground wire.
I want to add a light to this machine. What is the correct approach for wiring up a light using this power source?
I plan to use an LED bulb that supports 240v.

If you can source a 240V lamp, then wire it across the two hots.  No neutral required.  Obviously, if the lamp holder needs grounding, then ground it too.

I'd be kind of worried by using an ES base with the outer connected to a hot. Fortunately there are other bulb connectors like BC or Gu10 that don't give that risk.
There is an ES variant intended for 240V lamps but it is a different size to the more common 120V ES. And now you have a standards conflict where you want to use wold-voltage E26 lightbulbs but should use an E27 light bulb recpetacle.
If your machine works in the wet, obviously a sealed lamp enclosure would be warranted.
If the light bulb wires are thinner than the power feed to the machine (ie. too thin to carry 20A) then you should put in your machine fuses (or a 2 pole breaker) to protect the lamp wires
I feel that you should use a 2 pole switch for controlling the light, but I'm not certain that this is a requirement.
Label the light socket 240V in some place that will be obvious when you (or next person) has to change the light.

If your plug/receptacle is accessible it would likely satisfy the "disconnecting means" requirement for your equipment, but I notice NEC 410.93 requires the "switching device" of double pole lamp holders disconnect both poles. I'm not sure the code intent but it seems the difference in wording could be interpreted by AHJ that any switch to be double-pole. https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/4/equipment-for-general-use#410.93

The switch is for convenience, possibly you want to leave the machine plugged in and not have the light on all the time.  Does NEC apply to appliances? (not an electrical fitter or an electrician)

The modern trend is toward LED fixtures which are not socketed at all.  A socket is going to be problematic because it will either be a) highly alien and require bizarro bulbs to be obtained from the Euro market, or b) be able to accept 120V bulbs which may not be rated for 240V, resulting in potential explosion.
If you insist on using a socket, it will need to be a type which guards both terminals such as a Gu10, Gu24 or fluorescent style.  The kind with a shell and pin (Edison, bayonet, etc.) has the problem that the shell of socket and shell of bulb contact each other before the bulb is fully inserted.  Thus someone could be touching that shell (of the bulb) while it is in contact with the socket, putting one leg of 240V on their finger. Assuming the equipment is grounded, they are likely to be contacting that as well.

One other option would be to use a pair of tombstones and a ballast-bypass LED tube

6-20 means you have an actual receptacle like this Leviton from Home Depot:

If that's the case then you have a couple of options. You could hardwire the light by pigtailing the hots and ground (unless ground is automatic to metal box, which is a very good idea) of another cable or set of wires. You could also use a plug-in light if you replace the single receptacle with a double receptacle like this one:

Note however that changing a circuit might force you into 240V GFCI requirements. Historically 240V circuits have been exempt, but recent changes to the NEC have added requirements for GFCI in the usual areas (garage, unfinished basement, etc.) even on 240V circuits, if used with receptacles. Depending on NEC version, hardwired lights may be a way to avoid that requirement, which can only be satisfied with relatively expensive double-pole GFCI/breakers.
As others have pointed out, but which I missed in my initial read of the question, you are planning to use a light bulb, implying a light bulb socket. As others have pointed out, that may not be a very good idea due to the typical US light bulb socket designs - particularly the common Edison screw base - being designed for neutral as a relatively accessible and relatively safe exposed part, which won't be the case with a 240V fixture. So choose your socket/bulb type to avoid this problem or just get an integrated LED fixture. The old replaceable bulb mode is based on having to replace bulbs every 1,000 to 2,000 hours of use. However, a good quality integrated LED fixture will last a much longer time than that.
